# HDF5 file grows in size after overwriting the pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, hdf5, pytables

I'm trying to overwrite the pandas dataframe in hdf5 file. Each time I do this, the file size grows up while the stored frame content is the same. If I use mode='w' I lost all other records.
Is this a bug or am I missing something?

```
import pandas
df = pandas.read_csv('1.csv')
for i in range(100):
  store = pandas.HDFStore('tmp.h5')
  store.put('TMP', df)
  store.close()
```

The tmp.h5 grows in size.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Read the big warning at the bottom of this [section](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#delete-from-a-table)

This is how HDF5 works.

Comment: Thank you very much! Each time I close the store, I run h5repack tool and this solves the issue. The size doesn't grow.

Comment: Not so intuitive, maybe it offers an undelete option, that's why it keeps growing. I think you have to use a `subprocess` call from Python to shrink it down again as per this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21090432/4288043)